# Android: included layout not filling parent width

Tags: android, include

I have a main layout in which I include two inner layouts. I am specifying the width of the included layouts to match_parent but they don't occupy the entire width of the parent.

I may have more components in each inner LinearLayout for e.g., three left buttons and three right buttons. Below is a simplified example of my code

See example below:
main_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.95" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

            <include layout="@layout/child_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

            <include layout="@layout/child_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_weight="0.05"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:orientation="vertical">  

        <Button
           android:layout_width="80dp"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:textSize="14sp"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           android:text="Bottom" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

child_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Left" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rightLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

       <Button
           android:layout_width="80dp"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:textSize="14sp"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           android:text="Right" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Notice that the left and right buttons are overlapped in the image.[image]. How do I expand the included layout to fill the entire width of the parent so that the left and right buttons appear on left and right. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

In your `child` `layout`, take out your `LinearLayouts` then assign them to left and right of parent

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Left"
        android:layout_alignParntLeft="true" />


   <Button
       android:layout_width="80dp"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:textSize="14sp"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:text="Right" 
       android:layout_alignParntRight="true"/>
```

If I understand what you want then this should work. This will get them on the left and right but depending on if you want them on the same "line" or above or below each other then there are other attributes you can set

[RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)

`LinearLayout` can be very easy and useful when needed but using a `RelativeLayout` can often times eliminate nested `LinearLayout`s and useless `ViewGroup`s

Comment: I may have more components in each LinearLayout for e.g., three left buttons and three right buttons. I provided a simplified example of my code. Do I have to assign left and right to all the inner components?

Comment: Yes, wherever you want them to be. It seems like more work and harder to understand but, IMHO, `RelativeLayout` is mush easier to work with once you understand it. And it is much more flexible

Comment: I have added a note to my answer on my thoughts

Answer (score 0):

You can also get rid of several LinearLayouts and RelativeLayout and do this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
       android:layout_width="80dp"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:textSize="14sp"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:text="Left" />

    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:orientation="vertical" />

    <Button
       android:layout_width="80dp"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:textSize="14sp"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:text="Right" />
</LinearLayout>
```